# 'Invalid input shapes: expected 1 items got 16 items' when trying to quantize model for tflite

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-datasets

I was trying to quantise a TF model into a TFLite model to deploy it on my ESP32 by calling the dataset through `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` and used images_batch and labels_batch to iterate in the `representative dataset()` function. First, I was getting the error: 'EndVector() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given' but when I restarted the kernel it went away and now, I am getting 'Invalid input shapes: expected 1 items got 16 items'. I have tried absolutely everything but it just doesn't seem to work. Can someone please help me out?
Code sample of the quantizer with error:

```
def representative_dataset():
    for image_batch, labels_batch in val_ds:
        yield (image_batch)
# Set the optimization flag.
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
# Enforce integer only quantization
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8
# Provide a representative dataset to ensure we quantize correctly.
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
model_tflite = converter.convert()

# Save the model to disk
open('modelwithquant.tflite', "wb").write(model_tflite)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-31cc89ef97b4> in <module>
     13 # Provide a representative dataset to ensure we quantize correctly.
     14 converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
---> 15 model_tflite = converter.convert()
     16 
     17 # Save the model to disk

/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py in convert(self)
    919 
    920     if calibrate_and_quantize:
--> 921       result = self._calibrate_quantize_model(result, **flags)
    922 
    923     flags_modify_model_io_type = quant_mode.flags_modify_model_io_type(

/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py in _calibrate_quantize_model(self, result, inference_input_type, inference_output_type, activations_type, allow_float)
    519                                                 custom_op_registerers_by_func)
    520     if self._experimental_calibrate_only or self.experimental_new_quantizer:
--> 521       calibrated = calibrate_quantize.calibrate(
    522           self.representative_dataset.input_gen)
    523 

/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/optimize/calibrator.py in calibrate(self, dataset_gen)
    170       if not initialized:
    171         initialized = True
--> 172         self._calibrator.Prepare([list(s.shape) for s in sample])
    173       self._calibrator.FeedTensor(sample)
    174     return self._calibrator.Calibrate()

ValueError: Invalid input shapes: expected 1 items got 16 items.
```

Comment: You are passing batches of images ( batch size being 16 ) as the representative dataset. Call `val_ds.unbatch()` to unbatch the dataset and then iterate through it. Modify the line to `for image, labels in val_ds.unbatch()`.

Comment: "Invalid input shapes: expected 1 items got 64 items." I believe it is the imgsize now. Any way to mitigate this?

Comment: Try adding
```for image in image_batch.take(100):  yield [image]
   break
```